# Setting up a network share folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, homegroup, quickbooks

I'm trying to set up a network share folder for Windows 7 so we can use Quick books Enterprise 7.0 in multi user mode. I've tried everything that Quickbooks has said to do and everything in Windows 7, we've tried a homegroup, a shared folder mapped as a drive, etc. Nothing has worked, all the other files/folders show up on the other systems but not the folder we're storing our QB data in. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So when you map a drive directly to that QBData folder, you don't see the QB files?

Comment: We tried to map it to the QB folder but it wouldn't let us. We could map a drive to the parent folder but the QB folder wasn't there on the other systems on the network.

Comment: Was there an error message when you tried to map to the QB folder?

Comment: It just says that the folder isn't there... it doesn't have the permission to view it or something even though everything on the other computer (as far as I know) is configured to allow access to any computer on the network.

Comment: Were the permissions *explicitly* set on this folder to allow access to the Everyone group, or some other group?

Comment: Yes, they were set to allow the everyone group. Would a screen shot of the settings help out?

Comment: I'm also a little confused where the data should be, I have a copy of the folder with the QB data in both the Public uses QB company files folder and in the QB user account's documents folder.